# how to parse a markup element?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "<University id="1396677467961079" name="Oxford"/>";
```

I want to get value of id, so I could do this:

```
var id = str.Substring(16, 16);
```

but it is not a good way to get it. How can I get the value in a safer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML like this:

```
var str = "<University id=\"1396677467961079\" name=\"Oxford\"/>";
var el = XElement.Parse(str);
var attr = el.Attribute("id");
var id = attr != null ? attr.Value : string.Empty;
```

For an overview of Linq to Xml see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).